# Two instances of WordPress result randomly with status 301

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-swarm

I have exactly same containers containing WordPress app on docker swarm. They are both on the same network.
The problem is that after WordPress installation when I send GET to first app `curl -I $IP1` randomly I get response 301 with link to IP2...

The first question is - how the heck does one instance know about another? How can I debug what is the reason of such redirection?
And the main question is - how to fix it.

wordpress.yml

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    networks:
      - proxynet
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: changeme
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wp
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: changemetoo
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.role == manager

  word:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress
    networks:
      - proxynet
    volumes:
      - wp-content:/var/www/html
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wp
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: changemetoo


volumes:
  db-data:
  wp-content:
```

network.yml:

```
networks:
  proxynet:
    name: proxynet
```

part of wordpress log:

```
10.0.0.4 - - [25/Oct/2018:14:49:54 +0000] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 301 209 "-" "curl/7.35.0"
10.0.0.4 - - [25/Oct/2018:14:49:56 +0000] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 301 209 "-" "curl/7.35.0"
10.0.0.4 - - [25/Oct/2018:14:49:58 +0000] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 301 209 "-" "curl/7.35.0"
10.0.0.4 - - [25/Oct/2018:14:50:00 +0000] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 200 221 "-" "curl/7.35.0"
10.0.0.4 - - [25/Oct/2018:14:50:02 +0000] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 301 209 "-" "curl/7.35.0"
10.0.0.4 - - [25/Oct/2018:14:50:04 +0000] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 301 209 "-" "curl/7.35.0"
```

Comment: how do you deploy? did you scale word to 2 or do you have 2 stacks? where do you get the ip?

Comment: @Siyu  I have two separete stacks. And IPs I got from docker inspect.
(Sorry for late reply but I didn't get any notification :( )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought there was a bug in docker and I have created issue there.
But it was not.
If anyone would have a problem similar to this one, there is [splendid answer from @thaJeztah](https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/467) on github